# How i can use variables on json with Guzzle?

Tags: php, json, variables, guzzle

I'm trying to use variables in php to add values to the json on Guzzle, but that appear that's not working, i'm doing it wrong? Thanks in advance, im new in the use of Guzzle. (Guzzle 6)

```
$send_response = $send->post("https://yyy.com/services/" , [
  'headers' => [
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' .$token
  ],
  'json' => [
    'key' => $value,
    'key2' => $value2,
  ]
]);
```

Comment: According to [documentations](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#headers), I think your header is correct. Can you be more specific about your problem? What was the expected result of your request? What did you get instead?

Comment: And please inspect the [response object](https://guzzle3.readthedocs.io/http-client/response.html) (e.g. `var_dump($send_response->getStatusCode())`, `var_dump($send_response->getReasonPhrase())`, and `var_dump($send_response->getContentType())` for more hints.

Comment: hello, thanks for your time, i have a error in the tittle it must read: How i can use variables on JSON with Guzzle? i have this; 'json' => ['key'=>'value'] and works fine, but i need to pass the value by a variable like; 'json' => ['key'=>$value] when i do this way trows error: [{"errorCode":"APEX_ERROR","message":"Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCE (truncated...)

Im using Guzzle 6, thank you again!

Comment: That’s not a Guzzle error, that’s an error on the API you’re using. Review the data you’re sending it, or try and replicate the request in a tool like Postman.